# UIStickerBrowserView not resetting correctly in Stickers Application iOS 10

Tags: ios

I am creating a Stickers App in iOS 10 using the iMessage template project. I load the stickers and they look fine in compacted mode. I press the "^" arrow to transition to the expanded mode and then to the compacted mode again then I see the problem. The problem is that the Stickers for some reason do not start from the beginning of the UIStickersView as shown below: There is a gap on the top:

[image]

I have tried the following approaches and none of them worked:

```
//self.stickerBrowserView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

        self.stickerBrowserView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0 ),  animated: false)

        //self.stickerBrowserView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove Hello World from storyboard.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: @TobySpeight A storyboard is not code. Please be careful with those auto comments :)

Comment: @Undo, that's not obvious, given that the question includes a couple of lines of code, and there's no language tag.  Is the question even on-topic?

Comment: The question definitely is on-topic, @TobySpeight - Storyboards are a ["software tool commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Unclear, maybe, but not off-topic. I've done a little work with Stickers, and knew exactly what this answer was referring to. It's an attempt to answer the question, and thus belongs in an answer.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @Undo.